# need help binding to a WPF listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

You guys are so helpful and I had some trouble binding to a listview and was wondering if someone can help me, here is my code.

here is the xaml

```
    <ListView Name="ListView" Margin="0,0,16,145" ItemsSource="{Binding EmailCollection}" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="right" Width="704" IsEnabled="True" Background="White" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="#FF313131">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Pic}"  Width="140" Header="Picture"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Person}" Width="140" Header="Person" />
                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" Width="200" Header="Email" />
                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Location}" Width="160" Header="Location" />
                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Width="50" Header="Age" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

here I am trying to add an item to the person column but it says system.windows.controls.listviewitem does not contain a definition for person maybe I am missing something?

```
    ListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem {Person = t.InnerHtml});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the ListView is bound to an items collection, then you can't add to it directly.  Instead, do the following:

1. Make sure `EmailCollection` is of type `ObservableCollection`
2. Add the new item directly to the source `EmailCollection`

Comment: thanks, can you explain that in the code I have already, this was working fine the other day don't remember what I did before, the only difference is I was pulling data from mysql.

Comment: @chuckakers I can't think of how that would work -- that syntax is saying "create a new object and assign its property *Person*" ... only ListViewItem doesn't have that property.

Comment: @chuckakers Also ... you could use *ListView.Items.Add(new EmailItem { Person=t.InnerHtml })*, but then I believe you would get a different error (can't add to a ListView that is bound to an ItemsSource).

Comment: I remembered I used listView1.Items.Add(new {Person = "something here"}); and it's working now I just got to make sure I add to each column or I will have weird data in there like {Person = "something here"} that shows up in the columns that I haven't added an item to.

Comment: @chuckakers ah... nice.  I thought you couldn't both bind to the source and add items to the ListView.

Comment: yeagh it took me awhile i read your comment and remembered i didn't even put ListViewItem in there.